# Deploying Nightmare.js App To Heroku (Node.js + Telegraf)

Tags: node.js, heroku, nightmare

I want to deploy my app to heroku which contains web scraping using nightmare.js and my app doesn't work when deployed. What is the problem?
Here is the basic code...

```
bot.on('text', async (ctx) => {
  try{

    
    var input = ctx.message.text

    const def1 = await nightmare

      .goto('https://www.google.com/')
      
      .type('#term' ,input)
      .type('#term', '\u000d')
      
      .wait(200)

      .click('#rso > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.r > a > h3')

      .wait(200)

      .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#content > div:nth-child(1) > div.meaning').textContent)
      
      // .end()
      // .then(console.log)

      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      })


    console.log('def1 == ' + def1)
    
    await ctx.reply(def1)

  }

  catch(err){
    console.error(err)
  }


})
```

I have left out some basic require and init statements to make the code look simpler. And it doesn't have front end. it's all back end.

when i host it on heroku it does nothing. it says 'clean exit - waiting for changes'.

so what can i do to deploy my app to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information:

- Have you set "engines" in package.json?
- What exactly does the heroku log say?

Comment: no i haven't set engines in package.json...heroku logs say ' clean exit', it shows no error, but the command 'heroku local' works perfectly

Comment: try setting engines in package.json. That way you ensure that on heroku the same node version is used as you want it to be used.

Comment: node isnt the problem. nightmare is. heroku doesn't support nightmare